# Product structure in Frame

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

Is there a well known product structure for Frames? I.e. if $L$ and $L^{\prime}$ are frames, is there a product object in $\mathbf{Frm}$ category isomorphic to an object with underlying set the set product $L\times L^{\prime}$, and what is its order?

Also, I think this will be answered when the former is but just in case it won't, Is the case for coframes substantially different?

Comment: Frames are (infinitary) algebraic structures. Limits of algebraic structures are easy, you build them from the limits of underlying sets with pointwise operations.

Comment: It seems that some mods think this question is not worth this site, despite there is no a quick answer in the web to it, even more they didn't even take the time to leave a comment why is not well suited.  A shame that entitled behavior is observed in this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the question before trying to answer it because thought it would be harder or an obscure definition.

Anyway, the usual product order works over the usual set product:

$(x_{1},y_{1})\leq (x_{2},y_{2})$ iff $x_{1}\leq x_{2}$ and $y_{1}\leq y_{2}$.